# Angular2 simple run error

Tags: javascript, angular

Hey In my angular2 app I m gettign this error :

```
Potentially unhandled rejection [3] Error loading "app" at     http://localhost:8080/app.js
```

I m using official example, here is code :

**app.js**

```
 import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2';
 @Component({
   selector: 'my-app'
 })
 @View({
   template: '<h1>My first Angular 2 App</h1>'
 })
 class AppComponent {
 }
 bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

**index.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
     <script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>
     <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.26/angular2.dev.js">     </script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <my-app></my-app>
     <script>
       System.import('app');
     </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: in app.js change first line to from 'angular2/angular2'

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
@Component({
   selector: 'my-app'
})
@View({
   template: '<h1>My first Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
class AppComponent {
}
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using correct `import` statement.

Replace `import {Component, View, bootstrap} from angular2` with

```
   import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
   import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
```

Check the official Angular2 quick cheat sheet reference [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cheatsheet.html):

Answer (score 0):

As of `angular2@2.0.0-beta.0` the namespacing on imports has changed.

```js
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app'
})
@View({
  template: '<h1>My first Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
class AppComponent {}

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

If you're still using an alpha version the import should be

```js
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
```